# MultiColumn header with Datasource Kendo Grid

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid, multiple-columns

I have tried to search the internet for someone with the same problem...
I have an ordinary kendo-grid, where I have multiple column headers. I also have paging and pagesize on the grid.
My problem is, if I bind the model to the grid, it works, but it will reload the page every time I change the page or pagesize. If I use the datasource, the multicolumn header won't show the data for the cells beneath it. My code for the grid goes like this:

```
@Html.Kendo.Grid(Of ModelLayer.SomeType).Name("grdStuff").Columns(Function(column)
    column.Group(Function(gMedium)
        gMedium.Columns(Function(mediumColumns)
        End Function)
    End Function)
    column.Bound(Function(x) x.Name)
    column.Bound(Function(x) x.ConvenName)
    column.Bound(Function(x) x.ChemicalName)
    column.Bound(Function(x) x.Description)
    column.Group(Function(gMaterials)
        gMaterials.Title("Materials").Columns(Function(matColumn)
            matColumn.Bound(Function(xMat) xMat.LowAlloy)
            matColumn.Bound(Function(xMat) xMat.Ferritic)
            matColumn.Bound(Function(xMat) xMat.Austenitic)
            matColumn.Bound(Function(xMat) xMat.AusteniticMo)
        End Function)
    End Function)
 End Function).Pageable(Function(page)
     page.PageSizes(True)
     page.ButtonCount(3)
 End Function).DataSource(Function(datasource)
     datasource.Ajax.Read(Function(read) read.Action("Read", "controllerName"))
 End Function)
```

Anyone who has experienced the same or come up with a solution for using datasource?

**EDIT**

I want to use a static model without the multiheaded columns go bananas...

Comment: Is there really no one who can help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. Thought my scripts were updated, but apparantly it had only updated some of the other components :)